# Vertically align items in the center inside flew direction row

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, flexbox

I have some icon buttons inside a view which is pushed to the right of the container by flex direction row on the parent. Currently I cannot align them vertically in the middle of the container. Here is the code I have:
**JSX:**

```
<View style={styles.groupContainer}>
  <View style={styles.groupTextContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.groupText}>{title.toUpperCase()}</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={styles.groupButtonsContainer}>
    <Icon
      key={name + type}
      onPress={onPress}
      style={{marginLeft: 8}}
      name={name}
      type={type}
      color='silver' />
    <Icon
      key={name + type}
      onPress={onPress}
      style={{marginLeft: 8}}
      name={name}
      type={type}
      color='silver' />
  </View>
</View>
```

**styles:**

```
  groupContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#ddd',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  groupText: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: '#808080',
  },
  groupTextContainer: {
    padding: 10,
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
  },
  groupButtonsContainer: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
```

***UPDATE***
Forgot to mention that `Icon` is a `react-native-elements` component.
I need it to look like this:
[image: Buttons centered]

But I get this:
[image: Buttons at the bottom]

Comment: Sounds easy if you can attach the generated code/css or just create a simplified example

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted so far indicates that you shouldn't get the wanted output. Please post rendered markup along with its CSS. Also, by right click and choose _Inspect_, you might be able to track what goes wrong.

Comment: @LGSon updated my question, please, check again

Comment: @Huangism updated my question, please, check again

Comment: @zazu Can you attach the generated code or simplified generated code? From this css all I can see is that none of the elements have display flex defined

Comment: @Huangism I guess flex is a default display type on React Native

Answer (score 0):

```
<View style={styles.groupContainer}>
 <View style={styles.groupButtonsContainer}>
   <Text style={styles.groupText}>{title.toUpperCase()}</Text>
   <Icon
     key={name + type}
     onPress={onPress}
     style={{marginLeft: 8}}
     name={name}
     type={type}
     color='silver' />
 </View>
</View>
```

mybe you can follow this code and you restyle from text

Comment: Forgot to tell that I have more than 1 button and Icon is a `react-native-elements` component. However even if I put only 1 button, it appears under the text